# plots are printed on top of each other in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

> Blockquote

My code is something like this and I am running it on jupyter notebook:

```
powers = ["alpha", "beta", "low-gamma", "high-gamma"]
x_axis = np.arange(17) #number of subjects (n_subjects)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(4)

for ind_pow, pow_ in enumerate(powers):
    print("analysizing", pow_)
    res_0     = []
    res_01    = []
    res_001   = []
    res_0001  = []
    res_00001 = []
    for ind_sub in range(n_subjects):
        #some calculations to calculate res_0, res_01, et
        
    axs[ind_pow] = plt.plot(x_axis, np.array(res_0), "r", 
             x_axis, np.array(res_01), "b",
             x_axis, np.array(res_001), "g",
             x_axis, np.array(res_0001), "y",
             x_axis, np.array(res_00001), "k")
```

However, the results of figure are like this:

[image]

All the plots are plotted on the last one. I wonder what is wrong in the code.

`np.array(res_01)` (or similar ones) have the shape `(17, )`
Thanks

Also in another case, I want to write axs[ind_pow] = sns.heatmap(matrix)

The same problem exists. I do not know how to solve this as well

Comment: Uses `axs[ind_pow].plot` instead of `plt.plot`.

Comment: Esp. in jupyter, you can do multiple calls to the plt.plot function, without setting `fig, axs = plt.subplots(4)` and using `axs`. Then, after your loop, you should do a `plt.show()`